# What is a good python-based Webshop Software?

Tags: python, django, e-commerce, webshop

I am currently evaluating for an eCommerce project. Is there any good Python based webshop software. Are there any personal experiences people can share?

Until now I have only found:

- http://www.satchmoproject.com/

Coming from the PHP world finding only ONE project seams akward to me.

Does anybody have experience with Satchmo?

Are there any good commercial solutions? It's highly important that the webshop software is extendable (and if possible readable/changeable) in every aspect, but it's not required at all to be [OSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source_software). Commercial software with support deal is fair enough.

Any good recommendations out there?

Comment: A good rule of thumb to follow for Python vs PHP development is this: use Python if you're planning to write a program from scratch, and use PHP if you just want to modify an existing script.

Comment: hi yes i completly agree with your point. but DRY standard features of webshops would be anyway a timesaver :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Satchmo is a great project, mature, and used in live ecommerce sites.

The other up-and-coming Django ecommerce app that looks like it will be strong competition for Satchmo is [Lightning Fast Shop](http://www.getlfs.com/start).  I haven't used it, but I've looked over the code a few times and like its style.

Answer (score 11):

I also found:

- [Plata](http://plata-django-shop.readthedocs.org) (companion to the great FeinCMS)
- [Django-Shopkit](https://github.com/dokterbob/django-shopkit)
- [Django Shop](https://www.django-shop.org)
- [Satchless](http://satchless.com/)
- [Cartridge](http://cartridge.jupo.org/) (coupled with Mezzanine CMS)
- [Oscar](http://tangentlabs.github.com/django-oscar/)

I didn’t try any, was just looking for the right starting point myself (Oscar seems to be the only one that supports split payments, so I guess I'll use that).
See also http://www.readncode.com/blog/the-state-of-ecommerce-in-django/

Comment: I definitely would suggest oscar

Comment: Update: I never started with Oscar but forked Plata (see https://github.com/fiee/plata); since priorities shifted, I still don't have a completely running version.

Answer (score 1):

Satchmo is pretty good. I've used an older version, which lacked some of the built-in customisability of the more recent versions, but even so it was pretty easy to customise.

Don't forget that the one big advantage of OSS software is that even if the app itself doesn't expose a way to customise a particular bit of functionality, you've got the code right there so you can dive right in and change it.